# Moshi - convert string to object

Tags: android, moshi

I can't figure out how to do this in kotlin. I want to convert this string, to an object array:

```
[
{mode=bus, line=381, line_name=381, direction=Waterloo, operator=CX, date=2019-10-16, expected_departure_date=2019-10-16, aimed_departure_time=20:11, expected_departure_time=20:13, best_departure_estimate=20:13, source=Countdown instant, dir=outbound, operator_name=ABELLIO LONDON LIMITED, id=https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/route/CX/381/outbound/490010596E/2019-10-16/20:11/timetable.json?app_id=f56baf6a&app_key=6b0d065a1465ccbb6f32438f3d960803}, 

{mode=bus, line=381, line_name=381, direction=Waterloo, operator=CX, date=2019-10-16, expected_departure_date=2019-10-16, aimed_departure_time=20:33, expected_departure_time=20:34, best_departure_estimate=20:34, source=Countdown instant, dir=outbound, operator_name=ABELLIO LONDON LIMITED, id=https://transportapi.com/v3/uk/bus/route/CX/381/outbound/490010596E/2019-10-16/20:33/timetable.json?app_id=f56baf6a&app_key=6b0d065a1465ccbb6f32438f3d960803}
]
```

The object I want to convert it too:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class BusLive(val aimed_departure_time: String, val best_departure_estimate: String, val date: String, val dir: String,
    val direction: String,
    val expected_departure_date: String,
    val expected_departure_time: String,
    val id: String,
    val line: String,
    val line_name: String,
    val mode: String,
    val operator: String,
    val operator_name: String,
    val source: String
)
```

I've tried:

```
  fun moshiConverter(test:String) : String {
        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(LiveBus::class.java, LiveBus::class.java)
        val adapter:JsonAdapter<String> = moshi.adapter(type)
        val a = adapter.toJson(test)
        return a
    }
```

And no joy :(

Answer (score 2):

I hope what you posted as JSON as just an example. Because it is not valid JSON string.

To fix your example you have to change couple of lines:

```
    val type = Types.newParameterizedType(LiveBus::class.java, LiveBus::class.java)
    val adapter:JsonAdapter<String> = moshi.adapter(type)
```

to

```
    val type = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, LiveBus::class.java)
    val adapter = moshi.adapter(type)
```